# How to add an onclick event to a custom blazor tag

Tags: c#, html, blazor

I have a custom tag looks like the one bellow-
`DataRow.razor`

```
<div>
    @ChildContent
</div>
```

`DataRow.razor.cs`

```
public partial class DataRow
{
    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment? ChildContent { get; set; }
}
```

I want a way to add an `@onclick` event to the tag such that when the element is clicked it triggers an even in the parent

`parent.razor`

```
<DataRow @onclick="MyClickFun"></DataRow>

@code
{
     private void MyClickFun()
     {
       //code
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add an @onclick event to the DataRow component, you need to define an EventCallback in the DataRow component and then trigger it when the div is clicked.

```
<div @onclick="OnClicked">
    @ChildContent
</div>
```

```
public partial class DataRow
{
    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment? ChildContent { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback OnClick { get; set; }

    private async Task OnClicked(MouseEventArgs e) 
       => await OnClick.InvokeAsync();
}
```

```
<DataRow OnClick="MyClickFun"></DataRow>

@code
{
     private void MyClickFun()
     {
       //code
     }
}
```

Comment: Being very pedantic, you have a mismatch of signatures between the onclick event and the EventCallback.  Calling this method from `@onclick` handles that : `private async Task OnClicked(MouseEventArgs e) => await OnClick.InvokeAsync();`.   The compiler handles it here, but in other circumstances it may not.

Comment: Thank you, thats a valid point.  I've updated my answer.

Comment: No problem at all.   I get pedantic because others will read your answer and try to apply your solution out of context.